# Which one of my function declaration is better? generator or async/await?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, generator

I wanna write a function but I don't know which one of them is better:

```
function* call() {
    try {
        const a = yield api(1);
        const b = yield api(2);
        const c = yield api(3);
        const d = yield api(4);

        return [a, b, c, d];
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

or **Async/Await**:

```
async function call() {
    try {
        const a = await api(1);
        const b = await api(2);
        const c = await api(3);
        const d = await api(4);

        return [a, b, c, d];
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Both of them works well, I don't know which one of them is better or what is the difference between them.

Comment: https://thecodebarbarian.com/the-difference-between-async-await-and-generators Using `yield` when you can use `await` instead seems pretty strange, I think. If `api` only returns Promises, readers of your code will wonder what the purpose of the generator is

Comment: Don't they return different things? I thought the generator would only return a partial result on first call.

Comment: How it works the same?

Comment: @D_N Generators can be used to implement async/await (for example if async/await is not available, like in 2015) if you call the function using a trampoline (for example via the `co` module). However, since we now have async/await I'd consider it an anti-pattern (it's fine for 2015 though, but I prefer callbacks to generators - one of the reasons I never used the Koa framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not exactly the same, the differences are as follows:

1. The `call()` invocation with return you an iterator object for the generator `function*` whereas the `async` function will return you an array wrapped in a promise.
2. If you don't pass any value to the `iterator.next()` calls after getting it from the generator invocation, the resulting array you are returning from the generator function will have four `undefined` values. But in the `async` version you will get back the values returned from the `api()` calls in the Promise wrapped array.
3. Also the `yield` statements would return you the values when you iterate through the iterator, but in the `async` function the `await` will wait for the Promise returned by `api()` calls to be resolved then move on the next `await` else if the value is not a Promise from the `api()` call it will convert it to resolved Promise and the value of the `await` expression will become the value of the resolved Promise.

These three points can be illustrated below by a snippet.

1. Generator function:

```js
function* call() {
    try {
        const a = yield 1;
        const b = yield 2;
        const c = yield 3;
        const d = yield 4;

        return [a, b, c, d];
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
const itr = call();
//next() is not invoked with any params so the variables a, b, c, d will be undefiend
console.log(itr.next().value); 
console.log(itr.next().value);
console.log(itr.next().value);
console.log(itr.next().value);
console.log(itr.next().value);
```

2. Async function:

```js
async function call() {
    try {
        const a = await 1;
        const b = await 2;
        const c = await 3;
        const d = await 4;

        return [a, b, c, d];
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
//call() will return a Promise
call().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: Presumably the OP is using a trampoline library such as `co` to call the generator. Generators (or co-routines in other languages) and trampolines can be used to implement async/await as a design pattern instead of a language feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a generator function btw.

```
 function* call()
```

> The most important difference between async/await and generators is
>   that generators are natively supported all the way back to Node.js
>   4.x, whereas async/await requires Node.js >= 7.6.0. However, given that Node.js 4.x has already reached end-of-life and Node.js 6.x will
>   reach end-of-life in April 2019, this difference is rapidly becoming
>   irrelevant.
>   source: https://thecodebarbarian.com/the-difference-between-async-await-and-generators

Aysnc/Await offers a more concise approach to dealing with concurrency. But the generator functions offer more flexibility.

The choice depends on what you want to achieve, but in most cases, it makes sense to use async/await specially if you are using a modern version of NodeJs but